# How to change the input text colour in css web development

Tags: css, user-input

I am A novice coder(beginner) and I recently created a Netflix clone but there is one issue
in the inout placeholder whenever I type it comes in black colour but since the website is itself blackish its not clearly visible ....is there any way to change the input color

tried some inout placeholder functions all were in vain

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screen shot of the problem, and, if possible, the relevant parts of your HTML/CSS code.

Comment: Are you trying change the placeholder color or the input color (or both). Start by searching and you'll find useful stuff e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

Answer (score 0):

The `::placeholder` pseudo-element is used to style the placeholder text within the input field. You can set the `color` property to change the color of the placeholder text. You can select placeholder and add color in CSS.

Comment: not the color of the placeholder text but the input an user types in

Comment: So: <style>
input {
  color: red;
}
</style>
<input>

Answer (score 0):

Style your text inputs with a [color](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp) of your choice. In your CSS, add a rule like this:

```
input[type=text] {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Style your text inputs with a CSS color property. To change the text input colour. Try this code for solve the problem:

```
input[type=text] {
  color : #FFFFFF;
}
```